# Telegram BOT C# выводит не полную строку в сообщении

Tags: c#, telegram, бот

Есть такой код:

```
string temp = $"Топ-5 чарта Billboard на {Date}\n";

        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            temp += $"{i}.{Data.Content[$"{i}"].Artist} - {Data.Content[$"{i}"].Title}\n\n";
        } return temp;
```

Вывод в консоли:

```
1.Ariana Grande - 7 Rings

2.Marshmello & Bastille - Happier

3.Halsey - Without Me

4.Post Malone & Swae Lee - Sunflower (Spider-Man: Into The Spider-Verse)

5.Travis Scott - Sicko Mode
```

А в телеграме у бота выводиться только:

```
Топ-5 чарта Billboard на 2020-05-23
1.Ariana Grande - 7 Rings

2.Marshmello
```

Пытался выводить и вручную, и через цикл, разницы не было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При передаче строки в телеграм, он не воспринимает знак & в поле исполнителей

Просто в общей строке на вывод Temp.Replace("&", "featuring")

Comment: А как исправить-то?